# What is the difference of give to you. and give it to you?

Tags: future, clauses

> I will give you
>
> I will give **it to** you

Which one is correct?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about ELL.

Answer (score 1):

The correct usage depends on context.

> I will give you

usually is when something to be identified is to be given to you, for example:

> I will give you an upvote

The 2nd:

> I will give it to you

Generally refers to when the object ('it') to be given has already been identified or is known between both people.